# Allow moderators to choose a custom reason for locked posts

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, locked

<sup>I was sure this would be already posted somewhere, but couldn't find it - if it's a dupe, my apologies.</sup>

Currently moderators have the ability to **lock** a question or answer with one of several canned reasons: for instance, a "*historical lock*", for questions which are no longer considered good or on-topic but which are kept around because they have some historical value; or a "*content dispute*" lock, for questions which are currently undergoing edit wars.

But locking a question is an unusual thing to have to do, so all of this is just about edge cases. And of course edge cases are all special and different from one another. Questions may need to be locked for many different curious reasons, not all of which are covered by the existing canned "locked post" banners. Sometimes it would be nice to be able to create a special banner which only applies to one particular edge-case question, or even to tweak the text of one of the existing banners slightly.

**Would it be possible to grant moderators the ability to customise the "locked post" banners?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure that some of the locks are implemented differently.  For example I think historical locks prevent even editing whereas a wiki lock allows that to continue.  You may need to flesh out what properties a custom lock would have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For one-offs, just leave a comment. You can do that. You can even move the other comments to chat or just delete them if need-be.

Heck, edit a big-ass "**THIS QUESTION IS LOCKED BECAUSE OF SOMETHING THAT HAS NEVER HAPPENED BEFORE AND WILL NEVER HAPPEN AGAIN**" banner at the top of the post if you want. It's a unique occurrence, for which no one was prepared; extenuating circumstances and all that.

If you find yourself doing this a *lot*, then maybe you should be asking yourself - and others on your site - why so many posts need to be locked so often for so many weird reasons. Chances are, there's a deeper issue there.

On the other hand, if you find yourself repeatedly locking posts for the *same* reason... And it's a *good* reason... Then post a feature-request. Easy enough to add a custom lock reason for your site to handle whatever it is that comes up so often there that it's no longer expedient to be deleting comments and editing in obnoxious banners.

Comment: Good advice. And "*Easy enough to add a custom lock reason for your site*" - I didn't know that; thanks.